# python get class name from object

Tags: python, string, classname, args

I am trying to return a version number, with a way to implement exceptions.

Since the exceptions can be for any of my classes I am trying to get the classname from the object.

Problem is, I get a tuple instead of a string:

```
def version_control(*args):
    version = 1.0
    print args
    #Exception example:
    print str(args.__class__.__name__)
    if 'User' == args.__class__.__name__:
        version = 12.3

    return version
```

How can I change the `str(args.__class__.__name__)` in such a way that it return the name of the class as string?

Comment: No, you are not getting a tuple from `args.__class__.__name__`; something else is wrong. And why not use `if isinstance(args, User):` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I get a tuple instead of a string

No, you get the *string* `"tuple"` instead of *some other string*, because `args` is a tuple of arguments.

When you call `version_control(obj, 1, 2)`, `args == (obj, 1, 2)`. You want to be looking at `args[0]`, which in this example is `obj`

Comment: Excuse me first time working with args,  i guess i can solv this easier with kwargs then?

Comment: @HansdeJong: why would keyword arguments solve the problem? Your function is being called with positional arguments; just index the `args` tuple. How many different ways is this function being called?

Comment: i want to be able to put any of my objects (from most of my classes) in this  and only give an exception version when an object is passed that is in the exception list

http://pastebin.com/NGDHTN68   this seems to work fine

Comment: Sure, but since you didn't show us *how* the function is being called, we cannot help you with what arguments are being passed in either.

Comment: My excuses for that, still pretty new to django, python and stackoverflow.  Next time i try to be more precise

Answer (score 3):

##### To get the class name as a string:

```py
f = Foo()
f.__class__.__name__ # => 'Foo'
```

##### However, consider using `isinstance()` instead:

```
isinstance(f, Foo) # => True
```

This is more readable and covers a majority of use cases, and should be preferred when using a conditional.

Comment: Adding this answer here to provide a condensed tl;dr that directly addresses the question title, for users who googled 'python get classname from object' or something similar.

Comment: Credit to the comment on the question by Martijn Peters, which contains this information as well.